# Add text to picture in Windows Universal app

Tags: mobile, win-universal-app

I have universal app created for Win 10 mobile which captures photo. I want to add stamp (some text) to my photo. Is it possible? It seems working with bitmap is really difficult in universal applications

Answer (score 0):

Check this link:

[How to add wartermark text/image to a bitmap in Windows Store app](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-add-wartermark-f6313fad)

Or better use Win2D library (you can find it on NuGet) and snippet like this:

```
CanvasDevice device = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();
CanvasRenderTarget offscreen = new CanvasRenderTarget(device, 500, 500, 96);

cbi = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(device, "mydog.jpg");

using (var ds = offscreen.CreateDrawingSession())
{
  ds.DrawImage(cbi);

  var format = new CanvasTextFormat()
  {
    FontSize = 24,
    HorizontalAlignment = CanvasHorizontalAlignment.Left,
    VerticalAlignment = CanvasVerticalAlignment.Top,
    WordWrapping = CanvasWordWrapping.Wrap,
    FontFamily = "Tahoma"
  };

 var tl = new CanvasTextLayout(ds, "Some text", format, 200, 50); // width 200 and height 50

 ds.DrawTextLayout(tl, 10, 10, Colors.Black);

 tl.Dispose();
 }

 using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
 {
   stream.Seek(0);
   await offscreen.SaveAsync(stream, CanvasBitmapFileFormat.Png);

   BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
   image.SetSource(stream);
   img.Source = image;
 }
```